# Automating extracting values from existing commands

Tags: macros

(Part 1)

I'm trying to extract values or parameters from a predefined command to use in another command. Is this possible?

I'll add an example to clarify:

```
\fancypagestyle{c.appendix.sep}{
                \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.a}{$\leftarrow$ Naar \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R}} commando's} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{$\leftarrow$ Naar begrippenlijst }}}%
                \lfoot{\currentsection}
                \lhead{}
                \fancyhead[C]{}
}
```

Imagine I could extract say, rfoot value for reuse in another command?

---

(Part 2)

Is there any way to automate this over a range of commands, to only pick the very last declared object? (When choosing where to extract the value from)

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `fancyhdr` stores the `rfoot` values in `\f@ncyerf` and `\f@ncyorf`.

Comment: I didn't include an MWE because this question was not related to any specific packages or functionality thereof.

How do I call these values back and how far do they go back?

Comment: @Euryris there is no general mechanism, it relies on each command to have stored (or not) its arguments in internal macros. If you go `\newcommand\foo[1]{....#1___} then when executing `...` tex has no record that it is in the expansion of `\foo` TeX is a macro expansion language, it just works by textual substitution of the tokens, there is no call stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For part 1 of your question, I looked up, which macros are used to store values in `fancyhdr.sty`. It reveals, that the content of `\rfoot` is stored in `\f@ncyerf` and `\f@ncyorf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\rfoot{Hello footer}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
The \texttt{\string\rfoot} contains: \f@ncyorf
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Save the needed value in an own macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\Rfoot\rfoot
\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\def\LastRfoot{#1}\Rfoot{#1}}
\rfoot{Hello footer}

\begin{document}
The \texttt{\textbackslash rfoot} contains: \LastRfoot
\newpage
\rfoot{My new footer}
The \texttt{\textbackslash rfoot} contains: \LastRfoot
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this fails, if `\rfoot` was defined as `\outer\def\rfoot`.