# Automatic parsing/extraction of single-argument commands from input (for use in new environment)?

Tags: environments, tex-core, parsing

I'm not sure whether this is in principle possible, so let me try to explain; consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % current page text area
\usepackage{caption}
\pagecolor{yellow!15}

% convert rose: -resize 400x200! /tmp/test.png # ImageMagick

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}                    % {figure}[h!]
  \centering                        % %(for figure)
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{/tmp/test.png}
  \captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{    % \caption[shortdesc]{
  caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
  caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
  caption text line 03
  }
  \label{fig:test1}
  \end{center}                      % {figure}
  % \end

  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page/14514#14514
  % needs texing twice:
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Caption
    \node [anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth] (caption) at (current page text area.south west) {%
      \captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{ %
      caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
      caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
      caption text line 03
      }%
      \label{fig:test2} % has to stand after the caption, to get its number
    };
    % Image
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (caption.north) in
      node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (\x1,\y1) {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\imgheight{\y0-\y1-\abovecaptionskip}%
        \includegraphics[height=\imgheight pt,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{/tmp/test.png}%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

The first image snippet is my regular pattern of use of `{figure}` (or `{center}`, for non-floating) and `\includegraphics`. Occasionally though, I have to make images fit on bottom of page, for which I use the `tikz` pattern, as per [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page/14514#14514) - and that is the second image snippet.

Now, I always get mega frustrated when I wait for a minute for a doc to comile, realize the pic is not where I want, "maybe \vspace{-1em} will help"?, compile, wait, "Nope... maybe \clearpage"? ... etc until I realize I have to use the tikz pattern - which now requires me to rearrange the code snippet `:/`.

What I like about my typical pattern, is that its contents are basically just these three commands - and their (only) arguments:

```
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{/tmp/test.png}
\captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{    % \caption[shortdesc]{
  caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
  caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
  caption text line 03
}
\label{fig:test1}
```

... and then, I can basically just exchange `{figure}` for `{center}` (and `caption` for `\captionof`) without changing these innards much.

So, what I'd ultimately want to do, is define a new environment, say `{tikzbottomfigure}`, so I can write the same pattern inside:

```
\begin{tikzbottomfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{/tmp/test.png}
  \captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{    % \caption[shortdesc]{
    caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
    caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
    caption text line 03
  }
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{tikzbottomfigure}
```

... - and this is the part I'm unsure of - I'd want the new environment code to automatically extract the first command `\includegraphics...` and its arguments (all up to second command) into `#1`; the second command `\captionof...` and its contents into `#2`; and the `\label` and its contents into `#3` -- so that in the new environment definition code, I could simply write:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  % Caption
  \node [anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth] (caption) at (current page text area.south west) {%
    #2%
    #3% has to stand after the caption, to get its number
  };
  % Image
  \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (caption.north) in
    node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (\x1,\y1) {%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\imgheight{\y0-\y1-\abovecaptionskip}%
      #1%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Let's for the moment ignore the potential problems of `\includegraphics` not having the same arguments in both cases; my primary motive is to avoid defining a new environment with multiple arguments, which would force me to use braces to delimit arguments - and thus ultimately force me to rewrite image code snippets again, which is what I want to avoid in the first place.

The only way I can see this working, is if there is a mechanism that can parse/split and extract "commands and their arguments" from a chunk of text (and possibly assign them to individual `#1` type arguments later); notably, some commands may span several lines of text, so this shouldn't be just an (ASCII) text line splitter. So, ultimately, my question is - does such a parsing mechanism exist in Latex, so that I could apply it to my intended usage as described?

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125738/extracting-commands-from-environment ; http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173923/automating-extracting-values-from-existing-commands

Comment: My impression is that you want to define a command with a key-value argument: `\mycomm{caption=<text>,shortcaption=<short>,label=<label>,image=<file>,imageopts=<options>}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @egreg - actually, I want to avoid it; basically, I want to keep my usual (`{figure}`, `{center}`) usage pattern; and that kind of a `\mycomm` would require me to rewrite all images code to conform to that pattern. Basically, I'd keep my usual (`{figure}`, `{center}`) usage pattern as is during work; and if the time comes where bottom alignment is needed, I just change the environment name - instead of re-writing the entire snippet. My answer below shows a way, but probably not too robust. Cheers!

Comment: You can even have a key such as `format=figure` or `format=filltobottom` and others, which wouldn't require changing the environment's name, but just the value. Instead of an inflexible format like the one you want, a much more flexible approach.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I got somewhere, so I'll post this (the MWE, including some comments and links, is below) - an implementation of a `tikzbottomfigure` as required.

The thing is, since the commands we want to extract are individual tokens -- we can use definition of arguments in a `\def` to split at tokens; so we get our "parsing `\def`" function (here called `\splitfigurepattern`). One problem here is that the split contents may still contain commands, which may want to execute within the parsing `\def`. So, any \defs we use inside the parsing `\def` should be (eTex) `\protected` -- but this then forces a bit of `\expandafter` gymnastics when we want to get back at the data we extracted.

A second problem in that in a typical `\newenvironment`, we cannot really capture the contents between the `\begin{}` and the `\end{}` of the environment - because that would typically introduce unbalanced braces. So we must use `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package, which then provides the contents within an environment as `\BODY`, which we can use for the parser `\def` function.

Caveat emptor - note that if the contents within the environment, end up somehow *not* matching the input argument definition of the parsing `\def`, then Latex will crash with "Runaway argument"; so YMMV.

Here is the MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % current page text area
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{environ} % \BODY
% \usepackage{trace}
\pagecolor{yellow!15}

% convert rose: -resize 400x200! /tmp/test.png

% (c0)
% (c1)

% this one splits entire figure pattern, containing:
% \includegraphics[...]...\captionof...\label...
% (no need for external split call, as in (c1))
% still using protected, since arbitrary commands can appear wherever inside..
%\def\splitfigurepattern\includegraphics[#1]#2\captionof#3\label#4{%
% include #1 before \incl.graphics (to handle if a \centering there):
\def\splitfigurepattern#1\includegraphics[#2]#3\captionof#4\label#5{%
  \protected\def\sfpA{#2} % 'width=1.0\textwidth '
  \protected\def\sfpB{#3} % '{/tmp/test.png}'
  \protected\def\sfpC{#4} % '{figure}[shortdesc]{ caption lorem...03 }'
  \protected\def\sfpD{#5} % 'fig:test1'
  \protected\def\sfpO{#1} % '' if empty before \inclgr.; else '\centering'
  \typeout{sfp A: \meaning\sfpA^^J B: \meaning\sfpB^^J C: \meaning\sfpC^^J D: \meaning\sfpD^^J O: \meaning\sfpO} %
}
\def\runsplitfp#1{\splitfigurepattern#1\relax}

% (c2)

\NewEnviron{tikzbottomfigure}{%
  % call parser to split the argument
  % \expandafter\runsplitfp\BODY% ! Use of \splitfigurepattern doesn't match its definition.
  \expandafter\expandafter\runsplitfp{\BODY}% passes!
  %
  % here we should have parsed elements - proceed to output tikz code:
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-/14514#14514
  % needs texing twice:
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Caption
    % unless expanded properly, \label{\tmpD} will
    % fail with: "! Undefined control sequence. \sfpD"
    %\edef\tmpD{\sfpD}                                    % tmpD: \sfpD
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmpD\expandafter{\sfpD} % tmpD: fig:test2
    \typeout{tmpD: \tmpD}
    \node [anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth] (caption) at (current page text area.south west) {%
      \expandafter\captionof\sfpC
      \label{\tmpD} %
    };
    % Image
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmpB\expandafter{\sfpB} % better: File `{/tmp/test.png} ' not found.
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmpBB\tmpB \typeout{BB \tmpBB}% ok: BB /tmp/test.png
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (caption.north) in
      node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (\x1,\y1) {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\imgheight{\y0-\y1-\abovecaptionskip}%
        % (c3)
        \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\sfpA,height=\imgheight pt,
keepaspectratio,]{\tmpBB}%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
} % \NewEnviron{tikzbottomfigure}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}                    % {figure}[h!]
  \centering                        % %(for figure)
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{/tmp/test.png}
  \captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{    % \caption[shortdesc]{
  caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
  caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
  caption text line 03
  }
  \label{fig:test1}
  \end{center}                      % {figure}

  % (c4)

  text here ... \par
  ... to test figure scale on bottom\par
  ... to test figure bottom scaling\par
  ... to test figure scale - is ok.\par

  % \runsplitfp{%
  \begin{tikzbottomfigure}
  \centering % algo passes with or without this (prefix before \includegraphics)
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{/tmp/test.png}
  \captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{    % \caption[shortdesc]{
  caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
  caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
  caption text line 03
  }
  \label{fig:test2}
  \end{tikzbottomfigure}
  % } % \runsplitfp

% (c5)
\end{document}


% (c0)
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands
% using e-TeX's \protected system to prevent crashing at typeouts here!
% (just \string{#1} doesn't work)
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49056/optional-arguments-in-def
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/on-unprotecting-expanding-protected-macros-or-the-space-after-command-name
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14390/how-can-one-pass-the-contents-of-a-latex-environment-to-a-macro

\def\splitatcaptionof#1\captionof#2\relax{ %
  \protected\def\splcofA{#1} %
  \protected\def\splcofB{#2} %
  \typeout{A: \splcofA^^JB: \splcofB} % A: \splcofA  B: \splcofB
}
\def\testsplcof#1{\splitatcaptionof#1\relax}

% nope; croaks on [],{}
\def\splitfigurepatternOld\includegraphics\[#1\]\{#2\}\captionof#3\label#4{%
  \protected\def\sfpA{#1} %
  \protected\def\sfpB{#2} %
  \protected\def\sfpC{#3} %
  \protected\def\sfpD{#4} %
  \typeout{A: \meaning\sfpA^^J B: \meaning\sfpB^^J C: \meaning\sfpC^^J D:
\meaning\sfpD^^J }
}

% (c1)
% if the split character doesn't occur in input - runaway argument!
% if it does, the final #3 will contain a single character,
% unless we put in a "break" token; here just chose arbitrarily
% a previously undefined token `\e` ...
% this splits: ...[width=1.0\textwidth ]{/tmp/test.png}
\def\splitoneoptstr#1[#2]#3\e{%
  \def\soosA{#1} %
  \def\soosB{#2} %
  \def\soosC{#3} %
  \typeout{srp A: \meaning\soosA^^J B: \meaning\soosB^^J C: \meaning\soosC} %
}
% ... then, the call also must have the break token `\e` before the \relax:
\def\runsplitoos#1{\splitoneoptstr#1\e\relax}

% this one splits entire figure pattern, containing:
% \includegraphics...\captionof...\label...
% and uses \runsplitoos for the includegraphics opts
\def\splitfigurepattern\includegraphics#1\captionof#2\label#3{%
  \protected\def\sfpA{#1} %
  \protected\def\sfpB{#2} %
  \protected\def\sfpC{#3} %
  \typeout{sfp A: \meaning\sfpA^^J B: \meaning\sfpB^^J C: \meaning\sfpC } %
  % \expandafter\runsplitoos\sfpA % Runaway argument?
  \edef\tcp{\meaning\sfpA} \typeout{tcp \tcp} %
  % \expandafter\runsplitoos{\tcp} % Runaway argument?
  % \expandafter\runsplitoos\tcp % passes;
  \expandafter\expandafter\runsplitoos{\tcp} % passes;
}

% (c2)
\newenvironment{tikzbottomfigureNOPE}
{ % start \begin env.
% start calling \runsplitfp{%
\def\contents\begingroup % so we open a brace?
} % stop \begin env.
{ % start \end env.
\endgroup % \endgroup % close brace? cannot
} % stop end env.

% (c3)
% note, the \expandafter\edef must be outside of {node .. includegraphics},
% else spurious space is introduced!
%\traceon %
%\includegraphics[height=\imgheight pt,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{/tmp/test.png}%
%\includegraphics[height=\imgheight pt,\protect\sfpA,keepaspectratio]{\sfpB}%
% sfpA needs to be expanded here first? not really, it contains
% \textwidth; it just needs to be expanded before \includegraphics;
% same for "File `\sfpB ' not found."
%\edef\tmpB{\sfpB} % \tmpB ->\sfpB: ! LaTeX Error: File `\sfpB ' not found.
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmpB\expandafter{\sfpB} % better: File `{/tmp/test.png} ' not found.
% now one more edef to get rid of the braces:
% \edef\tmpBB\tmpB - undef; \edef\tmpBB{\tmpB} - same as before; has braces
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmpBB\tmpB \typeout{BB \tmpBB}% ok: BB /tmp/test.png
% finally the includegraphics - have to expand \sfpA
% inline here (as it may contain \textwidth etc):
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\sfpA,height=\imgheight pt,
keepaspectratio,]{\tmpBB}%

% (c4)
%   % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page/14514#14514
%   % needs texing twice:
%   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%     % Caption
%     \node [anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth] (caption) at (current page text area.south west) {%
%       \captionof{figure}[shortdesc]{ %
%       caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, text line 01
%       caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02
%       caption text line 03
%       }%
%       \label{fig:test2} % has to stand after the caption, to get its number
%     };
%     % Image
%     \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (caption.north) in
%       node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (\x1,\y1) {%
%         \pgfmathsetmacro\imgheight{\y0-\y1-\abovecaptionskip}%
%         \includegraphics[height=\imgheight pt,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{/tmp/test.png}%
%     };
%   \end{tikzpicture}%

% (c5)
% \edef\tcp{\meaning\sfpA} \typeout{tcp \tcp}
% \typeout{A: \meaning\splcofA^^JB: \meaning\splcofB}
% A: \protected macro:->\includegraphics [width=1.0\textwidth ]{/tmp/test.png}
% B: \protected macro:->{figure}[shortdesc]{ caption lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
% text line 01 caption consectetur adipisicing elit text line 02 caption text lin
% e 03 } \label {fig:test1}
```